# Cypress e2e testing. Unable to get primeng toast element to get text

Tags: cypress

I'm using cypress for e2e testing and I have primeng toast messages. I want the text present in toast but when I trigger toast and try to get the element but I'm unable to get the element.

primeng toast link:-     https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/toast.

Comment: Please supply more information. Can you inspect your element and show us what the HTML looks like? Also provide the cypress commands you are using to assert with. I am sure I or someone else will be able to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testing the toast message is bit tricky as the `toast` message will last only for a few seconds. You could probably add `cy.wait()` in this kind of situation. Another problem I have noted here is the following site  `https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/toast` has *got some delay in loading in cypress chrome 70 browser*. I have added tests for testing the `Success` and `Error` message text inside the toast. Added the screenshot of the passing tests.

```
describe('Find the toast message', function() {
   it('Test the toast message', function() {
    cy.visit('https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/toast')
    cy.get('button[label="Success"]').find('span').contains("Success").click({force:true})
    cy.wait(1000)
    cy.get('div.ui-toast-detail').invoke('text')
     .then((text)=>{
       const toastText = text;
       expect(toastText).to.equal("Order submitted");
     })
    cy.wait(1000)
     cy.get('button[label="Error"]').find('span').contains("Error").click({force:true})
     cy.wait(1000)
     cy.get('.ui-toast-message-content').find('div').find('div').contains("Validation failed").invoke('text')
      .then((text)=>{
        const toastText = text;
        expect(toastText).to.equal("Validation failed");
      })
   })
})
```

[image]