# Cypress E2E testing: How to test the text message on toast container (or) popup on a web page?

Tags: cypress, toastr

[screenshot of html code for the error toast popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Svg9.png)I am trying to get the element of popup (or) toast-container and asserting the text, but I am getting an error that element never found. Please someone help?

```
describe('Wholesoft Login Page', function(){

    it('Check Login popup', function(){

        cy.visit('https://https://platform.wholesoftmarket.com/login')
        cy.get('#email').type('kj@gmail.com')
        cy.get('#password').type('hello')
        cy.get('button.btn.active').click()
        cy.get('div').within(($div)=>{
            cy.get('div.overlay-container').should('have.text','no record found')
        }) 
    })
 })
```

Comment: Is there and iframe or shadow dom in your webpage ?

Comment: Shadow objects are there in page but the toast element is not included in that.

Comment: Your `cy.get('div')` is a bad choice. It is a generic selector and will return an array of `div` from DOM.

Comment: @jjhelguero I tried with different selectors and different methods but Cypress saying that element is not found. I am hardly trying to find the method to get the element of the toast popup.

Comment: I found this in but still not working for me "https://stackoverflow.com/a/53788996/18964198"

Comment: If you give a sample HTML of your popup, that would help narrow down your selector choice.

Comment: I have attached the link to screenshot of HTML code, I couldn't copy the code to paste here. Please check screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set a bigger timeout for the element, waiting to be present in the DOM:

```js
cy.get('div[aria-label="Error"]', {timeout: 10000}).should('have.text','no record found')
// maybe you can use the class selector on that div (div.toast-title.ng-star-inserted)
// default timeout is 6000
// increase it until it is caught by Cypress
```

Comment: That's great. Your solution is working for me, thanks. I couldn't vote your answer since I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: It is ok. Also, you can remove `.should('be.visible')`. It is redundant because the notification it is not hidden. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait till the toast or pop-up element is visible to access it for further steps.

Please make sure element selector is right.
following cmd

```
cy.get('div.overlay-container').should('be.visible').should('have.text','no record found')
```

Comment: I tried using the selector with above line but still Cypress saying "expected element never found". I know that Cypress accept the alert by default but I am not sure about this toast-container popup. I can't see the popup while running in Cypress. Kindly suggest. You also can check the website.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you did not override the default Toastify CSS classes, you may simply want to select the entity with something like:

```
cy.get('#root').within(() => {
  cy.get('.Toastify__toast-body').should(...your expectations here...)
})
```

(or replace #root by the id where your React app is rendered)

And as far as the timeout is of concern, just make sure that it is set equal or slightly greater than the 'autoClose' property of your ToastContainer component. Higher settings would just unnecessarily slower the tests flow.

Edit: the content of the .Toastify__toast-body div looks like this:
[.Toastify__toast-body  snapshot][1]

so it has four children: the icon, the text, a close button and a progress bar. In this particular case, I solved the problem using:

```
cy.get('.Toastify__toast-body').children().eq(1).should(...)
```

Hope this can help...
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9O5j.png